# How to change theme attribute in code?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme

Is there anyway to change theme attributes dynamically? For example,set the "android:colorPrimary" attribute for a Theme. I know I can apply different Themes to Activity when it creates, but it requires predefined styles in resources, which means the attributes are fixed. If I want to download one Theme from server(it can be a config file with some color attribute defined), this can't work out.

Comment: Did you find any solution since then?

Comment: No, I use give up using Theme， instead I defined a custom theme by json and build my UI dynamiclly